# How to read and copy the HTTP servlet response output stream content for logging

Tags: java, servlets, logging, servlet-filters

I've created a filter to in my java webserver (appengine actually) that logs the parameters of an incoming request. I'd also like to log the resulting response that my webserver writes. Although I have access to the response object, I'm not sure how to get the actual string/content response out of it.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you writing your response?  `response.getWriter().write(yourResponseString)`???  Or are you doing something different?  Are you wanting to write errors as well?  (In other words, do you want to log the response when you're doing `response.sendError(yourError)`??)

Comment: perhaps this http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/InterceptingFilter.html and this http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/jxslt/ch08_04.htm might give you a hint

Comment: @Dave just using response.getWriter().write(yourResponseString) as you mentioned and thats the old output I'd like to capture.

Comment: Using the TeeOutputStream to write into two outputstreams at time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28305057/1203628.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You need to create a [`Filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) wherein you wrap the `ServletResponse` argument with a custom [`HttpServletResponseWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html) implementation wherein you override the `getOutputStream()` and `getWriter()` to return a custom [`ServletOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletOutputStream.html) implementation wherein you copy the written byte(s) in the base abstract [`OutputStream#write(int b)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28int%29) method. Then, you pass the wrapped custom `HttpServletResponseWrapper` to the `FilterChain#doFilter()` call instead and finally you should be able to get the copied response *after* the the call.

In other words, the `Filter`:

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class ResponseLogger implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // NOOP.
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (response.getCharacterEncoding() == null) {
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); // Or whatever default. UTF-8 is good for World Domination.
        }

        HttpServletResponseCopier responseCopier = new HttpServletResponseCopier((HttpServletResponse) response);

        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, responseCopier);
            responseCopier.flushBuffer();
        } finally {
            byte[] copy = responseCopier.getCopy();
            System.out.println(new String(copy, response.getCharacterEncoding())); // Do your logging job here. This is just a basic example.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // NOOP.
    }

}
```

The custom `HttpServletResponseWrapper`:

```
public class HttpServletResponseCopier extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

    private ServletOutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private ServletOutputStreamCopier copier;

    public HttpServletResponseCopier(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        super(response);
    }

    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        if (writer != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("getWriter() has already been called on this response.");
        }

        if (outputStream == null) {
            outputStream = getResponse().getOutputStream();
            copier = new ServletOutputStreamCopier(outputStream);
        }

        return copier;
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("getOutputStream() has already been called on this response.");
        }

        if (writer == null) {
            copier = new ServletOutputStreamCopier(getResponse().getOutputStream());
            writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(copier, getResponse().getCharacterEncoding()), true);
        }

        return writer;
    }

    @Override
    public void flushBuffer() throws IOException {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.flush();
        } else if (outputStream != null) {
            copier.flush();
        }
    }

    public byte[] getCopy() {
        if (copier != null) {
            return copier.getCopy();
        } else {
            return new byte[0];
        }
    }

}
```

The custom `ServletOutputStream`:

```
public class ServletOutputStreamCopier extends ServletOutputStream {

    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream copy;

    public ServletOutputStreamCopier(OutputStream outputStream) {
        this.outputStream = outputStream;
        this.copy = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        outputStream.write(b);
        copy.write(b);
    }

    public byte[] getCopy() {
        return copy.toByteArray();
    }

}
```

Comment: The constructor name for `HttpServletResponseCopier` is incorrect, I can't edit it because the edit should be more than 6 characters long and I don't want to change anything else about the answer.

Comment: wondering why is it so complex to get the body of response. It should be something like response.getContent(). Must be some solid reasons behind it :)

Comment: @ant: It's memory hogging and usually not of interest for the webapp itself.

Comment: In my application I have to read the result of login json and if login result is 1 then create a session else don't create any session. I am  Using Spring/REST so its not possible for me to create HttpSession in spring. So I have to create session in doFilter. Just sharing a scenario where reading response content is required :)

Comment: @ant: just set a request attribute.

Comment: @BalusC: is it possible. I have posted my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744442/setting-request-response-attributes-in-spring-rest-environment

Comment: Great!! This solution also worked for me. Can somebody explain the code as well?

Comment: i read the code but not able to understand what exactly we are doing, please provide brief summary or comments with the functions.

Comment: Thanks for the comments

Comment: Finally a decent answer! Thanks

Comment: In case of Spring, starting at version 4.1.3, there's also [ContentCachingResponseWrapper](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/ContentCachingResponseWrapper.html).

Comment: @BalusC what's not clear is that your filter solution says you can log the response when the response may have not been made available yet. I think this combined with a ContainerResponseFilter will do the trick.

Comment: @BalusC is the reason why getOutputStream() checks if writer != null, and getWriter() checks is outputStream != null because once the response has started to be written with one, you can't attempt to also write with the other?

Comment: @KevinHooke Because the spec says so. See javadoc.

Comment: Thankyou very much!

Answer (score 16):

BalusC solution is ok, but little outdated. Spring now has feature for it . All you need to do is use `[ContentCachingResponseWrapper]`, which has method `public byte[] getContentAsByteArray()` .

I Suggest to make WrapperFactory which will allow to make it configurable, whether to use default ResponseWrapper or ContentCachingResponseWrapper.

Comment: How do you "use" it? From playing around a little with it, it looks like you replace the HttpServletResponseCopier with ContentCachingResponseWrapper -- is that correct?

Answer (score 14):

Instead of creating Custom HttpServletResponseWrapper.You can use ContentCachingResponseWrapper as it provide method getContentAsByteArray().

```
public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, HttpServletResponse servletResponse,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse response = servletResponse;
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper =new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
        try {
            super.doFilterInternal(requestWrapper, responseWrapper, filterChain);

        } finally {

            byte[] responseArray=responseWrapper.getContentAsByteArray();
            String responseStr=new String(responseArray,responseWrapper.getCharacterEncoding());
            System.out.println("string"+responseStr);       
            /*It is important to copy cached reponse body back to response stream
            to see response */
            responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Above solution from BalusC did not work for me but this one worked

Comment: needs spring though

Answer (score 5):

While [BalusC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8972088/1310733) will work in most scenarios you have to be careful with the `flush` call - it commits response and no other writing to it is possible, eg. via following filters.
We have found some problems with very simmilar approach in Websphere environment where the delivered response was only partial.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749730/when-is-servlet-response-committed-or-flushed) the flush should not be called at all and you should let it be called internally.

I have solved the flush problem by using `TeeWriter` (it splits stream into 2 streams) and using non-buffering streams in the "branched stream" for logging purpose. It is unneccessary to call the `flush` then.

```
private HttpServletResponse wrapResponseForLogging(HttpServletResponse response, final Writer branchedWriter) {
    return new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response) {
        PrintWriter writer;

        @Override
        public synchronized PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
            if (writer == null) {
                writer = new PrintWriter(new TeeWriter(super.getWriter(), branchedWriter));
            }
            return writer;
        }
    };
}
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
protected void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException {
    //...
    StringBuilderWriter branchedWriter = new org.apache.commons.io.output.StringBuilderWriter();
    try {
        chain.doFilter(request, wrapResponseForLogging(response, branchedWriter));
    } finally {
        log.trace("Response: " + branchedWriter);
    }
}
```

The code is simplified for brewity.

Answer (score 3):

I am not quite familiar with appengine but you need something [Access Log Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve) in Tomcat. Its attribute **pattern** ; a formatting layout identifying the various information fields from the request and response to be logged, or the word common or combined to select a standard format.

It looks appengine has built in functionality for [log filtering](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/logging.html).

[apply a servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770323/how-do-i-apply-a-servlet-filter-when-serving-an-html-page-directly)

Answer (score -2):

If you just want the response payload as as String, I would go for:

```java
final ReadableHttpServletResponse httpResponse = (ReadableHttpServletResponse) response;
final byte[] data = httpResponse.readPayload();
System.out.println(new String(data));
```

Comment: where is the ReadableHttpServletResponse coming from ?