# Setting request response attributes in Spring REST environment

Tags: spring, rest, attributes, httprequest, httpresponse

We have a Spring REST environment which is producing json response. Below is the code which is used to send the json response

```
@GET
@Path("/userinfo.json/{userid}")
@Produces("application/json")
public List<UserinfoBean> getUserAllInformation(@PathParam("userid") String userid) 
{
    return openServicesAPI.getUserAllInformation(userid);
}
```

Can anyone let me know how I can set the request/response attribute and if at all possible create an HTTPsession here.

Comment: What attribute of response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@Context`
this will give you the Contextual information

```
getUserAllInformation(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
@Context HttpServletResponse response,
@PathParam("userid") String userid){

//...

}
```