# How to scan entire HTML page using servlets?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am working on a reverse proxy solution with Java servlets and Apache Tomcat as a webserver,
my question how to intercept the HTTP request or server generated response and scan the entire text(HTML and script content) in it.Any suggestions,solutions or literature will appreciated. And suggestions are also required how to configure Tomcat running a reverse proxy or should i switch to some other Java web server.

Thanks in advance and sorry if question is incomplete any details required will be provided.

Comment: Have a look at this question: stackoverflow.com/questions/7138296/how-do-i-get-the-source-of-a-given-url-from-a-servlet

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to add a layer before serving response, You can add `Filter` and check for outbound response

Comment: Sure but to intercept the request what method should i use ? And then how to scan the entire content?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933054/how-to-log-response-content-from-a-java-web-server) is an example