# Scalatra response HMAC calulation

Tags: scala, servlets, hmac, scalatra

I'm developing a web service using Scalatra and I want to use HMAC for bidirectional authentication.

So far, I've implemented the client authentication to the server: the client (an Android app) calculates a HMAC/SHA512 for each request using these parameters: a shared secret, the HTTP method, URL, some headers (timestamp, clientId etc) and the request body (if it's a POST or a PUT). This HMAC is then added to a specific header and the request is sent to the server (which validates the HMAC in the request header with a HMAC that it calculates the same as the client).

Now, I want to do the opposite thing: have the server authenticate to the client using the stored shared secret, the request HTTP method, URL and the response **body**.

So far, I've found that I can override `renderResponse(actionResult: Any)`, `renderResponseBody(actionResult: Any)` or even `renderPipeline` and I've decided to go with overriding `renderPipeline` as it seems to be the easiest to handle.

In my overriden `renderPipeline` I transform the response body to a byte array (loading the served `File` in memory if serving a `File`), calculate the HMAC and add it to the `response` headers.

What I want to know is: are there cases when overriding `renderPipeline` this way would break either the authentication functionality presented above (like `renderPipeline` not being called or being called multiple times or the headers having been sent befor `renderPipeline` is called to render the body) or some other functionality in Scalatra?

As a note I do not calculate the HMAC when the action returns `Unit` and the response output is being written directly by the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem to solve. I used a trait extending `Handler`, just like it's done in the [GZipSupport.scala](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra/blob/9a676bab0572b5358b9b4a6ef381ea2d2a31037f/core/src/main/scala/org/scalatra/GZipSupport.scala) and using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8972088/1670855) as a reference implementation.

I built a `ServletOutputStreamCopier` which holds a copy of the original `OutputStream` and every byte to both streams:

```
class ServletOutputStreamCopier(orig: ServletOutputStream) extends ServletOutputStream {
    val copy: ByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024)

    override def write(b: Int): Unit = {
      orig.write(b)
      copy.write(b)
    }
    override def setWriteListener(writeListener: WriteListener): Unit = orig.setWriteListener(writeListener)

    override def isReady: Boolean = orig.isReady

    def getCopy: Array[Byte] = copy.toByteArray
}
```

Then a `ResponseCopier`, which is an `HttpServletResponseWrapper` with the previously defined `ServletOutputStreamCopier` and exposes the `copy` to the outside:

```
class ResponseCopier(res: HttpServletResponse, sos:   ServletOutputStreamCopier, w: PrintWriter) extends HttpServletResponseWrapper(res) {
    override def getOutputStream: ServletOutputStream = new ServletOutputStreamCopier(sos)

    override def getWriter: PrintWriter = w

    override def setContentLength(i: Int) = {}

    def getCopy: Array[Byte] = sos.getCopy
}
```

Finally the `handle` method takes care of adding the header after the Scalatra action was completed by using the callback `ScalatraBase.onRenderedComplete`.

```
trait SignedResponseSupport extends Handler {
  self: ScalatraBase =>

  abstract override def handle(req: HttpServletRequest, res: HttpServletResponse): Unit = {
    withRequestResponse(req, res) {
      val sosc = new ServletOutputStreamCopier(res.getOutputStream)
      val w = new PrintWriter(sosc)
      val wrapped = new ResponseCopier(response,sosc ,w)

      ScalatraBase.onRenderedCompleted { _ =>
        w.flush()
        w.close()
        val password = "secret-password"
        val signature = signResponseBody(wrapped.getCopy, password)
        wrapped.addHeader("X-Response-Signature", signature)
        }
      }
      super.handle(req, wrapped)
    }

  def signResponseBody(body: Array[Byte], password: String): String = {
    /*signing goes here*/
  }

}
```