# HttpServletResponseWrapper.toString() returns nothing in filter

Tags: java, servlets, filter

**My aim:** Inject any text into response.

**My Tries:** On various small projects I had successfully implemented a filter which alters the response.

**My Approach:** You may find all code at the bottom of my questions !
The problem I am facing is HttpServletResponseWrapper.toString() is returning "" when I put my code to huge web application( My project has many filter, security, spring and struts framework together, jsp and FTL views). When used on simple project the HttpServletResponseWrapper.getStatus() returns 304. But when used on my big application, the status returned is **200** (indicating the request succeeded normally). What happens at the end is un-altered response rendered to browser.

I would appreciate if I get any pointers to this issue from you. Thanks in advance. Below is the code I am using:

**LogFilter.java**

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class LogFilter implements Filter  {
    public void  init(FilterConfig config) 
            throws ServletException{

    }
    public void  doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
            ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) 
                    throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {


        System.out.println("BEFORE filter");

        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        CharResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new CharResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);

        chain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);

        System.out.println("status : "+responseWrapper.getStatus());
        String servletResponse = new String(responseWrapper.toString());

        out.write((servletResponse + " filtered all data without any issues <B>Hahaha :)</B>").getBytes()); // Here you can change the response


        System.out.println("AFTER filter, original response: "
                + servletResponse.toString());


    }
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

**CharResponseWrapper.java**

```
import java.io.CharArrayWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper;

public class CharResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
    private CharArrayWriter output;

    public String toString() {
        return output.toString();
    }

    public CharResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
        output = new CharArrayWriter();
    }

    public PrintWriter getWriter() {
        return new PrintWriter(output);
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
.
.
.
.
    <filter>
        <filter-name>LogFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.<<hidden>>.web.LogFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LogFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
.
.
.
```

Comment: The resource probably doesn't write to the response writer, but to the response output stream.

Comment: @JBNizet , you are right hence I used output.toString() while extending HttpServletResponseWrapper .

Comment: You didn't understand me. There are two ways to write things to an HTTP response: call `response.getWriter()`, and write characters to the returned writer. If that's what the resourse does, your wrapper will intercept it. Or call `response.getOutputStream()`, and write bytes to the returned OutputStream. If that's what the resource does, your wrapper will be unaware of it, since you didn't override getOutputStream()

Comment: Thank you very much @JBNizet. You are correct. After search  I got example at [check answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933054/how-to-log-response-content-from-a-java-web-server). And it is working now. I am closing my question!

Comment: Its now complicated. I am unable to get how the same code was working for other applications. Even though I didn't override getOutputStream, I was able to get expected output. Do anyone know whats the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @JBNizet. You are correct, I must override getOutputStream which I missed to implement. After searching more, I got an example at [check answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933054/how-to-log-response-content-from-a-java-web-server). And it is working now. I am closing my question!