# when is servlet response committed or flushed?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, forward, requestdispatcher

According to javadoc:

in-`request.getRequestDispatcher("/Test").forward(request,response);`

> forward should be called before the response has been committed to the
>   client (before response body output has been flushed).Uncommitted output in the response buffer is automatically cleared before the forward.

I am getting confused when this response is committed or been flushed?

is this writing in `println` of `printwriter`.

Comment: This Javadoc, for which class and method did you take this reference from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `flush()` on the `PrintWriter`commits the response.

`forward` method allows one servlet to do preliminary processing of a request and another resource to generate the response.

You can have many `out.write` statements before forwarding but you can't call `flush` before forwarding.
 like

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.write("forwarding...\n");
rd.forward(request, response); //this is good
```

but if

```
out.write("forwarding...\n");
 out.flush();
 rd.forward(request, response); //this throws an exception
```

Answer (score 0):

No it's not. 
Just when you flush it manually in your code like

`response.flush()`.

Normally the servlet container do it for you after "your" method.

Comment: as u said `Normally the servlet container do it for you after "your" method.` then every time u called forward within a method this is guaranteed uncommitted.