# Issue with RequestDispatcher including JSP programmatically in Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat7, weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm struggling with the following situation:

In our current web application running on Tomcat 7.0.64, we manage to include a JSP page via Java with the help of an own class `CharArrayWriterResponse implementing HttpServletResponseWrapper`.

The reason for doing so is that we wrap the resulting HTML into JSON needed for an AJAX Response.

Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>javax</groupId>
     <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
     <version>7.0</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
     <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Code example:

```
// somewhere in servlet doPost()/doGet()
try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
     out.println(getJspAsJson(request, response));
}

private static String getJspAsJson(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String html = getHtmlByJSP(request, response, "WEB-INF/path/to/existing.jsp");
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
    return "{\"results\":" + gson.toJson(html) + "}";
}

public static String getHtmlByJSP(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String jsp) {
     CharArrayWriterResponse customResponse = new CharArrayWriterResponse(response);
     request.getRequestDispatcher(jsp).include(request, customResponse);
     return customResponse.getOutput();
}

public class CharArrayWriterResponse extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
    private final CharArrayWriter charArray = new CharArrayWriter();

    public CharArrayWriterResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        // this is called ONLY in tomcat
        return new PrintWriter(charArray);
    }

    public String getOutput() {
        return charArray.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        // this is called ONLY in WebLogic
        return null; // don't know how to handle it
    }
}
```

Hint: I didn't consider exception handling in above code samples.

I have to migrate this application to WebLogic (12.2.1) but this solution is not working anymore.

What I found out so far:

In Tomcat after the call to `request.getRequestDispatcher(jsp).include()` of the example above `getWriter()` of my `CharArrayWriterResponse` class is called.

In WebLogic `getWriter()` is not called anymore and that's the reason why it doesn't work anymore.

After some debugging, I found out that in WebLogic instead of `getWriter()` only `getOutputStream()` is called if I override it.
`getWriter()` is not called once on Weblogic so there have to be differences in the underlying implementation of Tomcat and WebLogic.

Problem is that with `getOutputStream()` I see no possibility to get the response of the `include()` call in a separate stream or something else and to convert it to String for usage to build the final JSON containing the HTML.

Has someone solved this problem already and can provide a working solution for including a JSP in a programmatic way in combination with WebLogic?

Does anyone know another solution to achieve my goal?

Thanks for suggestions.

---

### Solution

See working example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42556442/7617251)

#### Hint

A difference I found out between Tomcat and new Weblogic solution:
With latter one it's not possible to include JSPF's directly anymore wheras with Tomcat `getWriter()` it is.

Solution is wrapping the JSPF inside a JSP file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this:

```
@Override
public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
    // this is called ONLY in WebLogic
    // created a custom outputstream that wraps your charArray
    return new CustomOutputStream(this.charArray);
}

// custom outputstream to wrap charArray writer
class CustomOutputStream extends ServletOutputStream {

    private WriterOutputStream out;

    public CustomOutputStream(CharArrayWriter writer) {
        // WriterOutputStream has a constructor without charset but it's deprecated, so change the UTF-8 charset to the one you use, if needed
        this.out = new WriterOutputStream(writer, "UTF-8");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReady() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setWriteListener(WriteListener writeListener) {
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        this.out.write(b);
        this.out.flush(); // it doesn't work without flushing
    }
}
```

I used `WriterOutputStream` from apache commons-io, so I had to include in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I don't know what's in your jsp file, but I've tested with a simple one and I believe it worked.
My jsp file:

```
<b>Hello world</b>

<p>testing</p>

<ul>test
<li>item</li>
<li>item2</li>
</ul>
```

Output (when accessing the servlet in a browser):

```
{"results":"<b>Hello world</b>\n\n<p>testing</p>\n\n<ul>test\n<li>item</li>\n<li>item2</li>\n</ul>"}
```

Comment: Hugo's solution is well oriented, but it misses an important detail: Method `getOutputStream` might be called **more than once** (which is what it is probabily happening in this case, since there are several URIs implied in the same chain). So, care must be taken to create a `CustomOutputStream`object *just once* and **store it** to be returned in the further calls to `getOutputStream`.

Comment: @Hugo Now it's working, thanks again for all your effort, Problem was that I missed the call to `flush()` in the `write()` method ;-).
Anyway the solution is not very fast so I'm looking into improving it further like you mentioned with BufferedOutputStream`. I'll provide the solution as **answer** here if it's finished.

Comment: Michael, you're welcome. You could also follow the suggestion made by @LittleSanti, I noticed that it really happens (lots of CustomOutputStream objects created), so there's also room for improvement at this point.

Comment: And, if you use a BufferedOutputStream, remember to give it a size big enough (multiple of 4Kb is recommended, minimum 4Kb).

Answer (score 2):

Here is my updated and working example how to include a JSP file programmatically if `getOutputStream()` instead of `getWriter()` is called when implementing `HttpServletResponseWrapper`:

```
public class MyServletOutputStream extends ServletOutputStream {

    private final BufferedOutputStream bufferedOut;

    public MyServletOutputStream(CharArrayWriter charArray) {
        this.bufferedOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new WriterOutputStream(charArray, "UTF-8"), 16384);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        this.bufferedOut.write(b);
    }

    /**
     * This is needed to get correct full content without anything missing
     */
    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        if (this.bufferedOut != null) {
            this.bufferedOut.flush();
        }
        super.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        this.bufferedOut.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReady() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setWriteListener(WriteListener writeListener) {
    }
}

public class CharArrayWriterResponse extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

    private final CharArrayWriter charArray = new CharArrayWriter();
    private ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream;

    public CharArrayWriterResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
    }

    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        if (servletOutputStream == null) {
            servletOutputStream = new MyServletOutputStream(this.charArray);
        }
        return servletOutputStream;
    }

    public String getOutputAndClose() {
        if (this.servletOutputStream != null) {
            try {
                // flush() is important to get complete content and not last "buffered" part missing
                this.servletOutputStream.flush()
                return this.charArray.toString();
            } finally {
                this.servletOutputStream.close()
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Empty (null) servletOutputStream not allowed");
    }

    // not necessary to override getWriter() if getOutputStream() is used by the "application server".
}

// ...somewhere in servlet process chain e.g. doGet()/doPost()
// request/response The original servlet request/response object e.g. from doGet/doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
CharArrayWriterResponse customResponse = new CharArrayWriterResponse(response);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/path/to/existing.jsp").include(request, customResponse);
String jspOutput = customResponse.getOutputAndClose();
// do some processing with jspOut e.g. wrap inside JSON

// customResponse.getOutputStream() is already closed by calling getOutputAndClose()
```

Comment: @Little Santi/@Hugo The solution above is working but I'm not 100% sure if my calls to `flush()` are correct. I also found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8972088/7617251) where `flushBuffer()` is also implemented. Maybe you both can double check this solution, thanks.

Comment: I'd try to call `flush` in `getOutput` method, or override `close` method in `MyServletOutputStream` (including a call to `flush` before closing it).

Comment: Another small question regarding the close(): Do I need a `customResponse.getOutputStream().close();`call in finally block around the `include()` or is it called "automagically" with the `close()` of the real response?

Comment: I'm not sure, but in my test I didn't need to do it (I just did [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440437/issue-with-requestdispatcher-including-jsp-programmatically-in-weblogic-12c/42562024#42562024) and it worked).
You could override `close` and put a System.out.println just to see if it's called (but I believe it is, although I'm not sure)

Comment: With overriden `close()` and breakpoint set inside it's never called. To release the resources correctly I think it's better to call `customResponse.getOutputStream().close();`like mentioned above.
@Little Santi What do you think about this?

Comment: My suggestions is to call close in `getOutput` method (inside a `finally` block, after `return` clause)
Like this: `try { return this.charArray.toString(); } finally { servletOutputStream.close(); }`
Note that I didn't need to call `flush` inside `getOutput` (like you did), for me it worked without it.

Comment: Updated my answer again by overriding close() and calling it in `getOutputAndClose()` (renamed from `getOutput()`. Also removed called to `flush()` in `getOutputStream()`.
I think you don't need the `flush()` call in `your `getOutput()`cause in your solution you call it in `write()` everytime.

Answer (score 2):

As I can't figure out how to put multi-line code inside comments, I'm just putting it here.
I could fix the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440437/issue-with-requestdispatcher-including-jsp-programmatically-in-weblogic-12c#comment-72251069)  by overriding `flush()` method in `MyServletOutputStream` class:

```
// inside MyServletOutputStream class
@Override
public void flush() throws IOException {
    if (this.bufferedOut != null) {
        this.bufferedOut.flush();
    }
    super.flush();
}
```