# Grails spring security, servlet filters, and respond

Tags: grails, spring-security

I need to extend spring security to hash the http response content and place the result inside of a header.  My approach is to create a servlet filter that reads the response and places the appropriate header. The filter is registered with spring security via a separate plugin.  The implementation is largely taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933054/how-to-log-response-content-from-a-java-web-server).

The entire setup works perfectly when the final application uses "render" in the controller to output JSON to the client.  However, if the same data is formatted via "respond" a 404 is returned to the client.  I am at a loss to explain the difference.

For reference everything is grails version 2.3.11 and spring security core version 2.0-RC4

Register the filter via my plugin's doWithSpring

```
responseHasher(ResponseHasher)

SpringSecurityUtils.registerFilter(
                'responseHasher', SecurityFilterPosition.LAST.order - 1)
```

My filter implementation

```
public class ResponseHasher implements Filter{

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                         ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {


        HttpServletResponseCopier wrapper = new HttpServletResponseCopier((HttpServletResponse)response);

        chain.doFilter(request, wrapper);
        wrapper.flushBuffer();

        /*
        Take the response, hash it, and set it in a header.  for brevity sake just prove we can read it for now
        and set a static header
        */
        byte[] copy = wrapper.getCopy();
        System.out.println(new String(copy, response.getCharacterEncoding()));
        wrapper.setHeader("foo","bar");

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

}
```

The HttpServletResponseCopier implementation.  The only change from the source is to override all 3 method signatures of write instead of just the one.

```
class HttpServletResponseCopier extends HttpServletResponseWrapper{

    private ServletOutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private ServletOutputStreamCopier copier;

    public HttpServletResponseCopier(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        super(response);
    }

    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        if (writer != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("getWriter() has already been called on this response.");
        }

        if (outputStream == null) {
            outputStream = getResponse().getOutputStream();
            copier = new ServletOutputStreamCopier(outputStream);
        }

        return copier;
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("getOutputStream() has already been called on this response.");
        }

        if (writer == null) {
            copier = new ServletOutputStreamCopier(getResponse().getOutputStream());
            writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(copier, getResponse().getCharacterEncoding()), true);
        }

        return writer;
    }

    @Override
    public void flushBuffer() throws IOException {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.flush();
        } else if (outputStream != null) {
            copier.flush();
        }
    }

    public byte[] getCopy() {
        if (copier != null) {
            return copier.getCopy();
        } else {
            return new byte[0];
        }
    }

    private class ServletOutputStreamCopier extends ServletOutputStream {

        private OutputStream outputStream;
        private ByteArrayOutputStream copy;

        public ServletOutputStreamCopier(OutputStream outputStream) {
            this.outputStream = outputStream;
            this.copy = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            outputStream.write(b);
            copy.write(b);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b,int off, int len) throws IOException {
            outputStream.write(b,off,len);
            copy.write(b,off,len);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            outputStream.write(b);
            copy.write(b);
        }

        public byte[] getCopy() {
            return copy.toByteArray();
        }

    }
}
```

And finally my controller method in the actual application

```
@Secured()
    def myAction() {
        def thing = Thing.get(1)  //thing can be any domain object really.  in this case we created thing 1 in bootstap

         //throws a 404
         respond(thing)
         /*
         works as expected, output is both rendered 
         and sent to system out, header "foo" is in response
         /*
         //render thing as JSON
}
```

Any insight would be appreciated as I do not understand why render would work and respond would not.  Additionally, I'm open to other approaches to solving this need if what I am attempting just will not work in grails.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the content negotiation: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.x/guide/single.html#contentNegotiation. Try to call the `myAction` with parameter `format=json` or add an `Accept` request header.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that and it had no affect.  I can attach a debugger and see that it least appears to be making it through the respond method and into the json renderer, kicking out valid JSON.  My (admittedly ignorant) guess  is the problem is somewhere farther down in the stack

Comment: Why don't you use default Grails Filters and put new header in `after()` section?

Answer (score 1):

I put all the project in grails, and got a similar problem. I had to make some changes.

For register, I used `SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter` method, as I was doing from a `Bootstrap.groovy` application.
Also, I declared the filter in `resources.groovy`

It worked with render, but 404 with respond. So changed the respond to:

```
respond user, [formats:['json']]
```

And it worked after I removed your filter. I got 404 whenever I put your filter and it was trying to find action.gsp.

I made a change in `ServletOutputStreamCopier`, implementing the delegates for `close` and `flush` methods, and it worked fine for render and respond:

```
class HttpServletResponseCopier extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

    private ServletOutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private ServletOutputStreamCopier copier;

    public HttpServletResponseCopier(HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        super(response);
    }

    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        if (writer != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "getWriter() has already been called on this response.");
        }

        if (outputStream == null) {
            outputStream = getResponse().getOutputStream();
            copier = new ServletOutputStreamCopier(outputStream);
        }

        return copier;
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "getOutputStream() has already been called on this response.");
        }

        if (writer == null) {
            copier = new ServletOutputStreamCopier(getResponse()
                    .getOutputStream());
            writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(copier,
                    getResponse().getCharacterEncoding()), true);
        }

        return writer;
    }

    @Override
    public void flushBuffer() throws IOException {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.flush();
        } else if (outputStream != null) {
            copier.flush();
        }
    }

    public byte[] getCopy() {
        if (copier != null) {
            return copier.getCopy();
        } else {
            return new byte[0];
        }
    }

    private class ServletOutputStreamCopier extends ServletOutputStream {

        private OutputStream outputStream;
        private ByteArrayOutputStream copy;

        public ServletOutputStreamCopier(OutputStream outputStream) {
            this.outputStream = outputStream;
            this.copy = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            outputStream.write(b);
            copy.write(b);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            outputStream.write(b, off, len);
            copy.write(b, off, len);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            outputStream.write(b);
            copy.write(b);
        }

        @Override
        public void flush() throws IOException {
            outputStream.flush();
            copy.flush();
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            outputStream.close();
            copy.close();
        }

        public byte[] getCopy() {
            return copy.toByteArray();
        }

    }
}
```

I didn't go through respond implementation details, but I think it get some confusion as it don't have a way to flush or close, and has a fallback to call the view instead of render json.

I know it is a little bit late, but now it is working.

resources.groovy

```
beans = {

    responseHasher(ResponseHasher){

    }

}
```

Boostrap.groovy

```
def init = { servletContext ->

    .

    SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter('responseHasher', SecurityFilterPosition.LAST.order - 1)

}
```

Best,
Eder