# HandlerInterceptor getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, exception, spring-boot

I am using Spring `@RestController` & sending response in Json format. That is working fine but i got requirement to send response to logger so i have implemented HandlerInterceptor of Spring and

```
@Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("--afterCompletion method executed--"+ request.getRequestURL());
    System.out.println("--afterCompletion method executed--"+ response.getWriter());
}
```

getting exception

--afterCompletion method executed--http://localhost:8080/login
2015-11-29 05:48:29.184 ERROR 9116 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain    : HandlerInterceptor.afterCompletion threw exception

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been
>   called for this response  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:578)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:212)
>     at
>   to.lookup.api.logger.LoggingInterceptor.afterCompletion(LoggingInterceptor.java:32)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in a spring interceptor because, when dealing with response's `OutputStream`, once you read a portion or a stream, its "consumed" and there no way to go back and read it again.

To enable the re-reads on a request, or a response, you would have to wrap the them and do so in the servlet filter, and than propagate the wrapped implementations down the filter chain.

You can find an already implemented wrappers that you can learn from, e.g. [spring-mvc-logger](https://github.com/isrsal/spring-mvc-logger). The implementation is based on  the [TeeInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html) which copies all the bytes read from `OutputStream` to a secondary `OutputStream` which allows re-reads.

Posting the code of the `ResponseWrapper` class used

```
   public class ResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

    private final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(bos);
    private long id;

    public ResponseWrapper(Long requestId, HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
        this.id = requestId;
    }

    @Override
    public ServletResponse getResponse() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        return new ServletOutputStream() {
            private TeeOutputStream tee = new TeeOutputStream(ResponseWrapper.super.getOutputStream(), bos);

            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                tee.write(b);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        return new TeePrintWriter(super.getWriter(), writer);
    }

    public byte[] toByteArray(){
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly.. I have added the link for a similar solution in my answer as well

Comment: Great, glad it helped

Answer (score -1):

afterCompletion is called after completion of request processing, that is, after rendering the view. Once the view is rendered, you cant use response.getWriter and hence you are getting the exception. What you can do is implement postHandle, which is called before the view rendering. 
If you still get error about response already being used then try following as well.

Add below config to web.xml

```
<jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
  </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

If the response is created in servlet, add below to servlets init param in web.xml

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>trimSpaces</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

For the logging of response, you might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933054/how-to-log-response-content-from-a-java-web-server).

Comment: getting the  exception in postHandle  but its now an different exception i tried flushing but still it's getting. 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:578)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:212)
 at to.lookup.api.logger.LoggingInterceptor.postHandle(LoggingInterceptor.java:25)

Comment: no giving same exception i am using spring boot implemented but still getting exception@Bean
 public ServletContextInitializer initializer() {
     return new ServletContextInitializer() {
   @Override
   public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    servletContext.setInitParameter("trimSpaces", "true");
   }
     };
 }