# Can HttpServletResponseWrapper implementation interfere with some http packets?

Tags: http, servlets, httpresponse, web.xml, servlet-filters

I am using the class HttpServletResponseCopier which extends HttpServletResponseWrapper, and the ServletOutputStreamCopier which extends ServletOutputStream. The code is at the top answer at [How to read and copy the HTTP servlet response output stream content for logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933054/how-to-log-response-content-from-a-java-web-server) and I use these in my servlet filter (in jboss for all /* url mapping)

For some http packets that go through my filter, I will modify the response body, but for others I will not. But for both, I call chain.dofilter(request, responseWrapper) where responseWrapper is of type HttpServletResponseCopier.

My question is whether using this reponseWrapper can interfere with normal operation of the existing web application (not mine) even if my servlet filter code does nothing at all with the responseWrapper?

The existing application is behaving differently in some cases, whereas its mostly working as before for other functionality. My aim is to find out how to fix the responseWrapper implementation as my filter does not do anything after chain.dofilter(request, responseWrapper), so I am asking if there's anything wrong in the wrapper implementation at the link above, that could explain why the application is behaving differently in some cases.

Comment: Define "differently"

Comment: The existing application is a PLM webapp that renders some part. I don't know the mechanism on how the rendering communicates but since all of the code is in a .war file, it must be some servlet and running over http.

Comment: The difference is that now the rendering fails with message unable to load the rendering viewer. I can't figure out why from the logs. Application is Siemens Teamcenter Active Workspace Client.