# How can we get the entity from HttpServletResponse?

Tags: java, spring, web, model-view-controller

The context is I want to migrate my Jersey Application to Spring MVC, For the Filter part, Jersey `ContainerRequestContext` has `getEntity()` function, which I can use to check response type is `MyClientResponse` or not

```
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {
    if (isMyClientResponse(responseContext.getEntity())) {}
```

but in spring Filter

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
```

the param `HttpServletResponse` doesn't have such method which I can extract the entity object from it

In Java `HttpServletResponse` class, I only see method like

```
public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException;
```

but don't see method like

```
public Object getEntity();
```

Which we can get the entity body from it, so how can we get entity from `HttpServletResponse`? Or is there any way to convert `ServletOutputStream` to Object?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the content of this response you mention?

Comment: Hi I have updated the question to make it more clearer

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933054/how-to-read-and-copy-the-http-servlet-response-output-stream-content-for-logging